# Weird error with semicolon

Tags: c#, uwp

I have this piece of code from one of my classes and when i hover over the semicolon next to "//error is here" "} Expected" but all the brackets are closed, i have no idea why its causing this, i tried rebuilding but nothing changes

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SQLite.Net;
using SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT;

    namespace HomeAutomation
    {
        public class MainCode
        {
            static string path = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.sqlite");
            static SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path)
            {
            conn.CreateTable<User>;//ERROR IS HERE
            }
        }

        public class User
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are for these square brackets surrounds your `conn.CreateTable<User>` line?

Comment: Parenthesis? createTable<user>(); ?

Comment: Have a read of this SO post for a working example... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24247435/getting-exception-when-using-sqlitenet

Comment: your code is incomplete, You need to review your guide book and see what is missing e.g. query or something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using an [object initiationalization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). You don't use semi-colon in it b/c a semi-colon indicates the termination point of a command. You're not allowed to end a statement in the middle of initialization. You would separate each field you're initializing with a comma and then end the statement after the  last curly brace.

**Edit**

It looks like you shouldn't be using object initialization after looking at the code again. This syntax is for initializing property on objects. You need to separate the two statments. I.e.

```
static SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path); // End initialization statement
static MainCode()
{
   conn.CreateTable<User>;//Initialize in static constructor
}
```

Comment: MainCode was the calss so i put everything in it and instead created a public void for conn.CreateTable it ended up working. Thanks for this though

Comment: np. Glad you got it working. I didn't know how you wanted it since it looked like you were trying to wrap it in a using statement. I just wanted to stress that you needed to initialize in a method call since you declared it as static in the class.

Comment: As a side note, are you disposing of the connection when you're done with it?

Answer (score 1):

This `conn.CreateTable<User>;//ERROR IS HERE` should read

`conn.CreateTable<User>();//solved`

You forgot the brackets

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help but maybe try:

```
conn.CreateTable<User>("SELECT somethingHere FROM somewhere");
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you've done here to use the keyword `static` when you should have used `using`

Looking at what you're trying to achieve I'd suggest your code might need to look something like:

`using SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path)
            {
            conn.CreateTable<User>();//ERROR IS HERE
            }`

What have I changed?
I've changed the word `static` to `using` and added the brackets to the end of the `conn.CreateTable<User>()`

Hope this helps!